# AJAX response is in [object Object] , jquery - hence unable to read it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Note**

> My question has been marked duplicate because I i learnt this that
>   localStorage can only save strings. Please refer to original question
>   in that case.

I am trying to read server response .Though this is very straight forward but I am not sure where I am wrong . I am tired of debugging after whole day of work .

This is my response from REST API :

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Im9rdXNlciIsImV4cCI6MTUxNjYxNDk2MywiZW1haWwiOiJkYWh1QGdhaWwuY29tIiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MTY2MTEzNjN9.BIno_cz8dQsb63bgobNtSQxpxbzlTfsnvtMr8H3EGVs",
    "user": {
        "pk": 2,
        "username": "okuser",
        "email": "dahu@gail.com",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": ""
    }
}
```

I can save key "token" and use it , but I am not able to get user.pk with this code :

```
  success: function(data) {

          //save JWT token
          localStorage.token = data.token;
          localStorage.user = data.user;
```

The user is am retrieving in some other function like this , where I am actually facing **user.pk as undefined** :

```
var user = localStorage.user;
  console.log("user pk : " + user.pk);
  if(!user)
  {
    somethingWentWrongHandler();
    return;
  }
```

In the above code "user" is present as [object  Object] but user.pk is undefined .

Comment: localstorage holds strings, not objects

Comment: The value of user is object, try console.dir(user) to see at console your object structure.

Comment: @epascarello , thats new learning , how can i store an object in localstorage ?

Comment: you can't you have to store a string.

Comment: You might need to JSON.stringify(data.user) and then access it by parsing it later

Comment: @ncdreamy sounds good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Localstorage holds strings, not objects so when you do `localStorage.user = data.user` it is just like `localStorage.user = data.user.toString();`

So you need to stringify it and parse it when you read it.

```
localStorage.user = JSON.stringify(data.user);  // store it
var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.user)  // read it
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only store string types in local storage.  So when you try to save the `user` object, it is converting it a a string of `[object Object]`.